# How can I identify whether or not a HighChart is displayed on screen?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using HighCharts (specifically highstock.js) to display a large number or charts on a page. Adjusting the extremes of a large number of charts takes 3-4 seconds (in my example). However, since only a fraction of the charts are available to the use to see on the page I'd like to set the extremes of only those charts that are visible.

https://jsfiddle.net/Eves/kapnLbwh/61/

```
var data = [];
var time = (new Date()).getTime();
for (i = -100; i <= 0; i++) {
  data.push({
    x: time + i * 1000,
    y: Math.random()
  });
}
var create = function(id) {
  $(document.body).append("<div id='c" + id.toString() + "'></div>");
  $('#c' + id.toString()).highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
      marginRight: 10,
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Value'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
          Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Random data',
      data: data
    }]
  });
}
var totalCharts = 177;
for (var i = 0; i < totalCharts; i++) {
  create(i);
}
var min = data[1].x;
var max = data[data.length - 2].x;
var startTime = moment();
for (var i = 0; i < totalCharts; i++) {
  var chart = $('#c' + i.toString()).highcharts();
  chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max);
  chart.redraw();
}
var endTime = moment();
var ms = moment(endTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(startTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss:SSS");
console.log(s.valueOf());
```

Obviously since screen sizes differ and users can potentially adjust the size of the panel/div/whatever where all of the highcharts are contained There are potentially a variable number of charts that will be viewable to the user.

Is there any way to determine which charts are viewable so that only those charts can have their extremes set?

And if so, can an event handle a check of which charts are viewable when the panel/div/whatever is altered (by size or scrolling) and then set those extremes of any new charts being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `getBoundingClientRect` method you can compare a chart container position with the current viewport:

```
function areChartsInViewport() {
    var charts = Highcharts.charts,
        bounding;

    charts.forEach(function(chart) {
        bounding = chart.container.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (
            bounding.bottom >= 0 &&
            bounding.top <=
            (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        ) {
            chart.isInViewport = true;
        } else {
            chart.isInViewport = false;
        }
    });
}

areChartsInViewport();

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    areChartsInViewport();
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tkj904be/

**Docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Useful example: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: Though I don't suppose anyone knows how to get the container for a yAxis? I actually have one chart with multiple yAxis so I need to know when one of them is in the viewport.

Comment: Hi @Eves, You can get the `yAxis` SVG group element through a chart instance: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oauv8k4m/